# How to send html request to a service url

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

How can I send html request from iPhone to `service url`.Can I take the whole html data in string and pass the `string variable` as one of `xml tag and POST request`?Do I need any conversions.

My html request is like this

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;&#xD;
        &lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;&#xD;
        &lt;head&gt;&#xD;
        &lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /&gt;&#xD;
        &lt;title&gt;Untitled Document&lt;/title&gt;&#xD;
        &lt;/head&gt;&#xD;
        &#xD;
        &lt;body style="background:#bdd9ef; padding:20px 0px; margin:0px;"&gt;&#xD;
            &lt;table width="700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-radius:10px; margin:0px auto; background:white; color:#2222; padding:20px 0px;" &gt;&#xD;
        &#xD;
................
................
```

I m doing it in the following way :

```
 NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XXX/services/Email.svc"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *contentType=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
        [request addValue:contentType5 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *postBody=[NSMutableData data];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EmailServiceRequest xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HtmlBody>%@</HtmlBody>",htmldata]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</EmailServiceRequest>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse=nil;
        NSError *error=nil;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                      returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                                  error:&error];

        if (responseData!= NULL)
        {
            NSString *rss = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
            NSLog(@"Response Code:%d",[urlResponse statusCode]);
            if([urlResponse statusCode ]>=200 && [urlResponse statusCode]<300)
            {
                NSLog(@"Response:%@",rss);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to send request: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

But I m getting error and unable to POST

Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSURLConnection` :
    Set your `NSURLRequest:` Use `requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL` to initialise the request.
    If you need to specify a `POST` request and/or `HTTP` headers, use `NSMutableURLRequest` with

```
    (void)setHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
    (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data
    (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field
```

Send your request in 2 ways using `NSURLConnection`:

```
    Synchronously: (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)
```

This returns a `NSData` variable that you can 
IMPORTANT: Remember to kick off the synchronous request in a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI.

```
    Asynchronously: (void)start
```

Don't forget to set your `NSURLConnection's` delegate to handle the connection as follows:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.data appendData:d];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Do anything you want with it 

    [responseText release];
}

// Handle basic authentication challenge if needed
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSString *username = @"username";
    NSString *password = @"password";

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                             password:password
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: But I have both HTML and XML  data.So what can I set content-type?and I have to pass that HTML request in xml format only like this :  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Body>%@</Body>",body]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];In such a case how can I do it.?

Comment: read this doc first. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have just posted my html request.Actually it is so long .Can u please have a look and let me know

Comment: did it in the way I edited in my question.But getting error.Where I m going wrong?